# Rust Split lines via white spaces: No method collect found for type &str

Tags: rust

I am trying to process output from the command line by line, and I stuck with the processing `str::Lines`.
I am trying to get for every line all words and process them (compare with some pattern)

My code:

```
// output came properly from command
let mut lines = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout).to_string().lines();

for line in lines {
    let vec: Vec<&str> = line.collect();

    // Try to do something with a split...
```

Compiler complains:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `collect` found for type `&str` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:218:39
    |
218 |             let vec: Vec<&str> = line.collect();
    |                                       ^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: the method `collect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `&mut &str : std::iter::Iterator`
            `&mut str : std::iter::Iterator`
```

I think I can probably copy line as a string and try to convert it but, because I am new in Rust would like to have some advice/help how I can turn line more smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to fix this issue, there were few things wrong in the example:

1. I needed String not lines because of lifetime
2. Mutability was not an issue here, so just removed
3. To iterate &str I needed extract Iterator? (not sure here, still, feel a little bit not comfortable with Rust docs...)

```
let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout).to_string();

for line in s.lines() {
    let vec: Vec<&str> = line.split(' ').collect();

    // Try to do something with a split...
```

Comment: *"To iterate &str I needed extract Iterator"* no, you don't need to `collect` it to iterate over it. Just do `for splitted in line.split(' ') { ... }`